# CloudFront + Amazon WAF with another host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-waf, amazon-cloudfront

I've an website hosted on DigitalOcean and I'm trying for days to figure how to protect it using amazon cloudfornt + amazon waf is this even possible?

I read amazon documentation but it's not useful,I even watched a lot of you tube videos, but 99% of them are just doing the job using with an amazon hosted website.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck ? AWS WAF is integrated with Amazon CloudFront, which supports custom origins outside of AWS So it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set your digital ocean website as the origin in CloudFront. You will of course want to block traffic to your digital ocean website that isn't from CloudFront. You can add a secret header that Cloudfront will pass to the origin that you can require on your backend. You can also consider whitelisting all AWS CloudFront [IPs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LocationsOfEdgeServers.html).